# Is there a sediment from clearing pectin haze?

Tags: wine, sediment, pectic-enzyme

Does the use of pectic enzyme leave a sediment as pectin haze clears?  I have a couple gallons of jalapeno wine with a diluted apple base that I have added additional pectic enzyme to, and I'm ready to bottle it up and let the enzyme work in the bottle unless it will leave a sediment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes there is.**

Pectine is cleared by hydrolysis, pectine molecules are broken down and will sediment as pectine flakes.  Those sediments are often called fine lees, and will float above the heavier gross lees.

There are good (french) articles on wikipedia, confirming this:

- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9bourbage
- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectine